# How to iterate the scopes of all of the connected apps to my account?

Tags: soql, rest-api, soap-api, metadata-api, connected-apps

I was asking [How should one fetch Application Permissions via API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/354257/102737), but apparently it wasn't so clear, so I'll try to rephrase it. What I am trying to do, is to fetch thru API the scopes of all of the connected apps that are not part of my organization.

For example, I installed Slack, and when navigating to its connected app page, I see the following:

[image]

Therefore I know the application has scopes, yet I can't figure out how to fetch those neither thru the SOAP API nor thru the metadat API.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You won't be able to fetch scopes of apps that are not installed in your org. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @identigral! Why do you think it is not installed in my org? I've installed it thru the marketplace, and I have the `uninstall` button, doesn't it mean it is installed?

Comment: You wrote: _fetch thru API the scopes of all of the connected apps that are not part of my organization_ . If you meant _fetch thru API the scopes of all of the connected apps that are installed in my org_, then doesn't [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354257/retrieving-oauth-scopes-from-an-installed-connected-app) Q&A answer it?

Comment: Not really, because iget in this call only the applications that I created, and not all of the applications that were installed in my org. By _not part of my org_ I meant external applications that other vendors created.

Comment: There's no API for this. You have to request an access token via the app and [introspect it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305477/oauth-introspection-endpoint-says-a-valid-access-token-is-inactive)

Comment: Thanks @identigral! But can I acquire a token for an application that doesn't have the api scope?

Comment: Good question. A bit of a catch-22 with scopes you'd have to know upfront to request but there are only a few possibilities: `web`, `api` and a [few others](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5)

Comment: @identigral, I am pretty sure I can't. Only the owner of the application (the one that created it) has the consumer key & secret. Therefore I have no way to generate a token for it.

Comment: Consumer secret isn't needed for most flows but consumer key is not exposed.  Unfortunately it seems that you'll have parse the HTML from the UI via UI automation tool such as Selenium.

Comment: @identigral that's exactly what I tried to avoid... thank you very much for your help!