# Easy way to do a daily check to see if OAuth2 Connected App is authorized correctly and can access data via API?

Tags: api, query, oauth2, authorization

I want to do a daily check to see if my Connected App (that is authorized with OAuth2) has a valid authorization and I can query information from the Org using the API.

Is there a way to directly check if the Connected App's authorization has expired or not?

My original idea was to do a simple daily query via REST API (for example, SELECT Id FROM Organization), and if I get the Org Id then I have a valid authorization, and if I get an error like "Invalid Session Id", then I have to re-authorize. However, I was wondering if there was an API Call designed *specifically* to check if the authorization is valid or not.

Thanks!

Comment: I would write some code on the external app to handle authorisation failure and then notify.

Comment: No, there's no URL specifically designed to check the status of an access token. Performing a query, as you've outlined here, is probably the best option.

Comment: [Introspection endpoint](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oidc_token_introspection_endpoint.htm&type=5) does this. There's important detail in [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305477/oauth-introspection-endpoint-says-a-valid-access-token-is-inactive).